# Linq statement for returning next ID

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have list of `Books` with PK of `Id` and some of `Books` may deleted.
for example list with this `Id`s:

1 2 5 6 8

now I need a linq statement to return next insertion Id (in example "3")

I tried this code but it always `return` "1":

```
 public int GetNextRecordId()
    {
        List<Book> books = getAll();
        int counted = books.Count();
        foreach (Book b in books)
        {
            if (books.Where(book => book.Id == (b.Id + 1)) == null)
                return b.Id + 1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why would you want to reuse Id's?  Why not just add one to the last Id?

Comment: @lanMercer because I want use resources in best way.my application will have a large number of delete and insertion and I won't use `long` for `Id`!

Comment: @lanMercer Nice point! I will consider it.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing I notice right away is that this will never be true:

```
books.Where(book => book.Id == (b.Id + 1)) == null
```

The Where call returns an empty enumerable if it finds no matches.  Start from there.

Try this instead:

```
!books.Where(book => book.Id == (b.Id + 1)).Any()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large number of books you probably can't hold them all in memory like that.  And you certainly don't want to be doing a loop over them with a `Where` clause in it iterating over them again.  You would be better off reading them sequentially to look for a gap like this:-

```
public int GetNextRecordId()
{
    // Cannot load all books into memory ...
    IEnumerable<Book> books = dataContext.Books.OrderBy(b => b.Id);

    int index = 0;
    foreach (var book in books)
    {
      index++;
      if (index < book.Id) return index;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: as you know I'm beginner ,so I want to know storing all books in `IEnumerable<Book> books` will not fill the memory?

Comment: It will not fill memory, in fact, until the `foreach` loop executes it will not even make a request to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this linq query, if this query run on linq to entites, cost of query is very low:

```
var id = books.Select(p => p.Id  + 1).Except(books.Select(p=>p.Id)).First();
```